# Can superfluids communicate faster than light?

Tags: faster-than-light, superfluidity

According to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ueVTzEB3tJ8

A superfluid "flows without friction" and "all of the atoms in a superfluid are in the same quantum state." What strikes me as odd is the statement "all [the atoms] have the same momentum, such that if one of them moves, they all move."

This sounds a lot like the basis of FTL communication but maybe it's an oversimplification. Can someone clarify?

Comment: If I remember correctly, a superfluid can't flow faster than the speed of sound in that fluid. Something to do with the propagation of waves. And, if that's the case, then no information can move faster than the waves.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the momentum of a single atom in the superfluid it would by the definition you gave above no longer be a superfluid. It would not force the other atoms to adapt to the change instantaneously. So the answear is no, of course superfluidity does not imply faster than light communication between the atoms.